# What is wrong in doing this (considering a parallel make)?

Tags: makefile

I have 2 dirs A and within A I have B.

Makefile in directory A looks like :

```
include rules.mk            //defines common rules for generating *.o from *.cpp *.c

OBJECTS = test.o \
          B\test1.o \
          B\test2.o

test.lo : $(OBJECTS)
   $(LD) $(LD_OPTS) -o $@ $^
   $(CREATE_CXX_SO)
```

As is B doesn't have a Makefile defined within it.

Is it mandatory for having Makefiles within the subdirs as well? For serial makes this doesn't seem to pose a problem but while doing parallel makes at times `$(LD)` tries making `conn.lo` even before `B/test1.o` and `B/test2.o` are compiled.

If what I am doing above is wrong, what are the options that I have?

Comment: Is this (part of) the actual makefile you're using, or did you write this up to look like the actual one you're using? I'm asking, because you mention the target `conn.lo`, but this is not seen in the code you posted. The short snippet you show looks alright to me. Check if your actual makefile really does the same as the piece you showed us here.

Answer (score 0):

I read an excellent article about the recursive use of `make` at... you guessed it, [Recursive Make Considered Harmful](http://miller.emu.id.au/pmiller/books/rmch/). This article details the problems with the distressingly common recursive use of `make`, and how to build your `Makefile` such that it can run better and more reliably in parallel.

Or, you can use [SCons](http://scons.org) which works brilliantly.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but if you notice here, there no recursive make invocation which is involved here. I wanted to know if make as such mandates one to have a makefile per directory and if one doesnt do that what are the side effects.

Comment: No, make doesn't require one Makefile per directory. In fact, as that article describes, it's better to have *one* Makefile, and to include files from subdirectories as part of the master Makefile.